# Jquery after mouseover make a fake(the mouse remains in) div of around +100px

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

using the mouseover api of jquery is easy.
But what I want is that when the mouseover function gets evoked I want to create a virtual/fake div of lets say 100px around the div and when the user drags out of the virtual  div I want to provoke a function.

How can I create the virtual div ?
And assign the jquery's function .mouseout to the virtual div ?

Please help me
Thanks

Comment: Use a 'mouseenter' event for the creation of the div. If you do 'mouseover', you'd create a large number of divs for every little movement within the target div.

Comment: Yea yea but mouseenter and mouseover are not 'A lot different' and i used mouseover cus there "MAYBE" be some people who dont know the mouseenter. So ...

Comment: You're not making any sense, especially that last comment.

Comment: _So ..._ what are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to be looking at something like this: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/VA9qS/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="trigger"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('div.outer').live("mouseleave", function(e) {
    $('.trigger', this).unwrap();
});

$('.trigger').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<div class='outer'>");
});
```

***Caveat***: I've used `jQuery 1.5.2` on the jsfiddle example as both `1.6` and `edge` display some strangely-different behaviours. `1.6` fails to work as the `mouseleave` event is fired when leaving the child element (`trigger`) ([bug details are here](http://dev.jquery.it/ticket/9069)), and `edge` fires the `mouseenter` event for `trigger` each time.  This is workaroundable (which is now a word) by checking the `className` of the `parent`, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/VA9qS/3/).  This is all in Chrome 12.